# Discord Bot Slash Command Embed with Buttons

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am creating a discord bot with a slash command called join that suppose to display information then allow the user to click on the button to decide on which one they want. But the embed displays but the buttons do no appear at all.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const {Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permissions, ActionRowBuilder} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, 
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]});

client.on("ready", (c) => {
    console.log("Bot is ready!")
    console.log(`${c.user.tag} is online.`);
});

module.exports = {
    async execute() {
        const c5Row = ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('c5')
            .setLabel('Continent 5')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        )
        const c4Row = ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('c4')
        .setLabel('Continent 4')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        )
        const c3Row = ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('c3')
        .setLabel('Continent 3')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        )
        const c2row = ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('c2')
        .setLabel('Continent 2')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        )
        const c1Row = ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('c1')
        .setLabel('Continent 1')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        )


        client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
            if(!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
            if(interaction.commandName === 'join') {
                const { ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

                const c1Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle("Continent 1")
                .setDescription("Hephae Saturdays 11pm-2pm EST | Campbosh Saturdays 7pm-11pm | Ryanm_gm Saturdays 7pm-11pm EST")
                .setColor('Purple');

                const c2Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle("Continent 2")
                .setDescription("Fat_Viking Saturdays 2pm-5pm EST | Knight_Ed Tuesday 3pm-6pm EST")
                .setColor('Purple');

                const c3Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle("Continent 3")
                .setDescription("Raspy Screams Saturdays 6pm-9pm EST | GeekGirlLyssa Mondays 1pm- 5pm EST | DM Jesse Thursdays 4pm-7pm EST | LordRevan30 Friday 1pm-4pm EST | Logan_btw Thursday 3pm-6pm EST")
                .setColor('Purple');

                const c4Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle("Continent 4")
                .setDescription("FatAssNinja1999 Saturdays 1pm-4pm EST | Sulcax Sundays 1pm-4pm EST | wizardking23 Tuesday 7pm-10pm EST | jakeiguess Friday 10pm-1am EST | old Omen Monday or Friday 5pm-8pm EST")
                .setColor('Purple');

                const c5Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle("Continent 5")
                .setDescription("Stratosfyr Tuesdays 7pm-10pm EST, Firemaker282 Wednesdays 7pm-11pm EST")
                .setColor('Purple');
                
                interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed,c1Embed,c2Embed,c3Embed,c4Embed,c5Embed], components:[c1Row,c2row]});
                
            }
        })
    },
};
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I tried rewriting multiple times in different ways but I get the same results.